# Angular: Append dynamic created component as a child of the target-Element

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-dynamic-components

I'm implementing a directive to add actions to a mat-table's mat-cell:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell
    *matCellDef="let row"
    tableActions
    [editAction]="true"
    [actionInputData]="actionInputData"
    [row]="row"
  >
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

**tableActions** is the directive. My goal ist to append the actions as a child of mat-cell.

I've already tried lots of ways and I've searched a lot but haven't found any way to do that in a way, that all works as expected:

1. I used the **_viewContainerRef** to create and append the action but the action is alaways added next to the mat-cell and not as a child.

   **let componentRef: ComponentRef = this._viewContainerRef.createComponent(component);**

[image]

2. I used Angular's renderer (Renderer2). It worked to append the component as a child of mat-cell but the mat-icon, mat-tooltip and Angular's standard directives such as *ngIf don't work. It seems so that all directives added to the action's html don't work.

Here I created the componentRef with the angular core's createComponent-function and appended it to the target-Element (mat-cell)

```
  let componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = createComponent(component, {
    environmentInjector: this._appRef.injector,
  }); 

  this._renderer.appendChild(
    this._elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement,
    componentRef.location.nativeElement
  );
```

[image]

The edit action's html is:

```
<button
  mat-icon-button
  (click)="editRow(row)"
  color="primary"
  matTooltip="{{ 'edit' | translate }}"
>
  <mat-icon color="primary">edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```

**My final question is:** How can I append these action-components in a way that all is working as I would implement them directly into the mat-cell?

Comment: Please share a minimal issue stackblitz with the issue reproduced for debugging!

Comment: I shared enough details that you can help me without a stackblitz. Why do you want a stackblitz then?

Comment: You're right not needed, my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It started working for me, by doing the below steps,

1. Ensuring the imports are added (`CommonModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule`) to the component that is going to be rendered dynamically
2. Using the `setInput` method to create the binding needed for the angular component, else binding will not work for `@Input`
3. Running the change detection of the child component, so that the component changes are detected, using `componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();`

rendered component

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-action-container',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule],
  template: `
  <button mat-button color="primary" *ngIf="show">
    asdf
    <mat-icon color="primary"></mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button mat-button color="primary" *ngIf="!show">
    qwer
    <mat-icon color="primary"></mat-icon>
  </button>
  `,
  styleUrl: './table-action-container.component.scss',
})
export class TableActionContainerComponent {
  @Input() show = false;
}
```

directive

```
import {
  ApplicationRef,
  ComponentRef,
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  Renderer2,
  createComponent,
} from '@angular/core';
import { TableActionContainerComponent } from './table-action-container/table-action-container.component';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTableActions]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class TableActionsDirective {
  @Input() show = false;
  constructor(
    private _appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private _renderer: Renderer2,
    private _elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const component = TableActionContainerComponent;
    let componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = createComponent(component, {
      environmentInjector: this._appRef.injector,
    });
    componentRef.setInput('show', this.show);

    this._renderer.appendChild(
      this._elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement,
      componentRef.location.nativeElement
    );
    componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

html snippet

```
  ...
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Action</th>
    <td
      mat-cell
      *matCellDef="let element;let index = index"
      appTableActions
      [show]="index % 2 === 0"
    ></td>
  </ng-container>
  ...
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dxlaz7-zhgslf?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-actions.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-action-container%2Ftable-action-container.component.html,src%2Fexample%2Ftable-basic-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-action-container%2Ftable-action-container.component.ts,src%2Fexample%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-actions.directive.spec.ts)

Comment: The mat-tooltip still doesn't work. I just moved my mouse on the element to trigger the mat-tooltip and now the label isn't dispayed.  I use the mat-tooltip as a directive ( matTooltip="{{ 'edit' | translate }}" ). Do you have any idea, why the label isn't displayed?

Comment: @Stefan Have you added the module `MatTooltipModule` to the child component?

Comment: I use a shared-Module which imports and exports the MatTooltipModule. If I implement the actions directly it works. But if I use the Renderer2 to append it to the DOM it doesn't work.

Comment: @Stefan please share back the stackblitz with the issue replicated, if possible a new question since its a new issue!